# Mod Rewrite - How to point main site to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've domain using wildcard dns but I want my main site *example.com* will grab content from folder `/home/` by example.

1. If user type *http://www.example.com/*
   or *http://example.com/* site will read
   file from subfolder `/public_html/home/`
2. If *http://subdomain.example.com/* will reading content from `/public_html/`.

Let me know how to that in my .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule !^home/ home%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need htaccess or mod-rewrite for that. just config your site's document root dir to be /var/www/home/ or whatever you want it.

for example, in apache2 you can put this in apache-dir/sites-enabled/000-default/

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mail@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/home/
        <Location "/">
                allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ok thanks mate. the problem I have no access to httpd conf :)